# Converting from tensorflow frozen graph to tflite for android inference

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, onnx, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert from pytorch to tflite for android inference for a app I'm working on that uses real-time camera data of basketball to create a heatmap of made and missed shots. It's already working for iOS. [Here's a demo](https://www.myshotcount.com/).

I've managed to convert from pytorch (.pth) to onnx and from onnx to a tensorflow frozen graph (.pb). Inference on that tf frozen graph checks out.

However, when I try to convert from the frozen graph to tflite, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Inputs and outputs not all float|uint8|int16 types.Node number 2 (ADD) failed to invoke.`

Input details from the interpreter [interpreter.get_input_details(), interpreter.get_output_details()] suggest the datatype is numpy.float32, which is where I'm confused. Shouldn't that qualify as float? Any suggestions/help will be much appreciated!

```
[{'name': 'image', 'index': 21904, 'shape': array([  3, width, height], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
[{'name': 'action', 'index': 7204, 'shape': array([], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
```

From tensorflow's documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

The inference file for tensorflow frozen graph (1.14.0) for anyone in need:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

w = ...
h = ...

class CNN(object):

    def __init__(self, model_filepath):
        self.model_filepath = model_filepath
        self.load_graph(model_filepath = self.model_filepath)

    def load_graph(self, model_filepath):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()

        with tf.gfile.GFile(model_filepath, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

        with self.graph.as_default():
            self.input = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape = [3, h, w], name='image')
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, {'image': self.input})

        self.graph.finalize()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph = self.graph)

    def test(self, data):
        output_tensor = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/action:0')
        output = self.sess.run(output_tensor, feed_dict = {self.input: data})
        return output

def main():
    nn = CNN(model_filepath='out_1.14.pb')
    img = np.asarray(Image.open('example.jpg')).astype(np.float32)
    img = img.transpose(-1, 0, 1)
    ans = nn.test(data=img)
    print(ans)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try to give a tensor as input to `interpreter.set_tensor(...)` method instead of a numpy array. Or try with different tf versions, I had a similar issue, it worked for me with tf1.13.1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Oswald. I changed input to ```input_tensor = tf.zeros([height, width, 3])``` and the error is ```ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got tensor of type STRING but expected type FLOAT32 for input 21904, name: image```. Also tried 1.15 and 1.13.1, but same issue as before.

Comment: I believe this should be working with the right configuration, for my usecase I was able run my model with by inputting a numpy array in `set_tensor(..)`, with these configurations `python==3.6.7`, `tensorflow==1.14.0`, `numpy==1.17.3` and windows-10. but my node was expecting integer, so I casted my numpy arrays to np.int32